# Display turns off after two minute of inactivity and won't come back on until I restart

Tags: display, lock-screen

My system requires a restart when its screen gets off. Once I've left my system it locks after 2 minutes and the display goes off but when I press any button or mouse clicks it never turn on, It turns on only when I restart by holding the power button.

I'm currently using 18.04.2.

Comment: What is your monitor? Is it a laptop or external TV?

Comment: My monitor is a laptop display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved, when I installed the extension Unblack-screen-saver. Currently I am not facing any issues in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Your question says you are using 16.04 and don't want to upgrade. Your answer 9 months later says you are using 18.04 and an extension to solve problem.

Comment: Yes, I upgaraded the my machine, so I decided to give 18 a try.